# How can I display html in webview?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I've been using retrofit2 to get a response from the server and get an html String.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
~~~~
```

I checked that this is normal html. After converting the content to html, open it

However, I tried using loadDataWithBaseURL, loadData, etc. to apply it to the webview, but it does not open, so I ask a question.

my webView setting

```
hashWebView.settings.apply {
                setSupportMultipleWindows(false)
                setSupportZoom(false)
                javaScriptEnabled = true
                javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false
                loadWithOverviewMode = true
                useWideViewPort = true
                builtInZoomControls = false
                displayZoomControls = false
                layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN
                cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
                domStorageEnabled = true
                databaseEnabled = true

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                }
            }
            hashWebView.apply {
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

                //loadData(it,"text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8" )

                val encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(it.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_PADDING)
                loadDataWithBaseURL(null, encodedHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null)
            }
```

where it is an html string value

How can I open this html string in webview?

Comment: You should not base64 encode your html source string. Use it as is.

Comment: blackapps //It is the same even if you use it as is

Comment: `checked that this is normal html. After converting the content to html,` ??? If it is normal html then there is nothing to convert. What do you mean?

Comment: blackapps// sorry bro, just retrofit2 error